How to keep the colors of each cube when I use a Realize Instances node?
The position and color data come from a .CSV file. Each cube has its own color. How can I keep the colors after using the Realize Instances node?

with the realize instances blocks

Is there a solution?

Try to store the attribute after the realize.
If you need, capture the atribe before realize and store after.

You do not need the Capture Attribute node - you have not plugged in anything there so it does not capture any data anyway.
Three things:

First of all, if you want to render the object with Cycles, I would not use the name "color" for the attribute - at least in my experience when I use it, it often does not work correctly (EEVEE does not seem to have this problem), maybe this is a reserved internal attribute for Cycles. So in my example I use the name "pos_color" just to make sure it works in both Cycles and EEVEE. In general, when creating my own custom attributes I try to come up with names which are unlikely to be already implemented in Blender.

Then your Store Named Attribute node is set to store the data on points - which usually does not work with instances. Probably this works because you have the data from some CSV file attached to the points on which you are instancing (because you read it from a Named Attribute node), I do not know and I cannot reproduce it here because I have no CSV file and do not know how it is implemented on your object. I just would say, normally you set the Store Named Attribute to Instances, when you want to store data on instances.

Because if you have done that, the Realize Instance node would naturally copy the stored attribute data from the instances to the vertices created by the respective instance. You do not show your material setup, but with data stored on instances you would use an Attribute node set to Type: Instancer in the Shader Editor. And then after realizing the instances, these instances become geometry so you simply need to switch the Attribute node to Type: Geometry and the color will be there again.
Before realizing the instances:

After realizing the instances:



Oh, and just for comparison: these are the results for EEVEE and Cycles if I would use the attribute name "color", here with Geometry. With Instancer this problem does not exist, so I suspect the attribute "color" is reserved for vertex colors. Which leads me to believe, your CSV data is stored in a vertex color attribute.


Thank you so much, it works, you're a champion.

@FrançoisCardon You'Re welcome. You might consider accepting the answer then.
